# vb.net json deserialize into a dataset

Tags: vb.net, json.net, dataset, converters

Im getting an odd issue with NewtonSoft JSON in converting a JSON string to a Dataset or String-based Dictionary.

```
 dim TheJsonInstruction  as string = "{
    ""id"": ""qh06fx6"",
    ""data"": {
    ""name"": ""john"",
    ""age"": ""30""
    }
  }"

    Dim dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(TheJsonInstruction)
```

even if I try to do this into a dictionary as so:

```
  Dim values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(TheJsonInstruction)
```

I get an error of: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'data', line 3, position 10.'

Its like it does not like the format but a JSONLint online says its a valid JSON string.

What am I missing here, driving me bonkers!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the pourpouse of this? You can not convert it directly to a string dictionary or dataset but why  do you need it?

Comment: We have a winforms app that will communicate via webview control, some data that will be sent back may contain a list of items, the string I provided above was just an example json string - I am wondering why it cannot be converted to a dictionary string, would it need to be in a different format, i.e. the data { and } removed with just name and age to do it?
An example of real-world response (just an event listener) picks up this:
{"id":"60ohw66",""type":"demoEventWithResponse","data":{"message":"""}}

Im guessing the same issue is for that?

Comment: `Dictionary(Of String, String)` fails because the value of `"data"` is not a string, it's a JSON object.  A JSON object cannot be deserialized to a string without some custom converter.

Comment: `DataSet` fails because the JSON format for DataSet, a shown in [Deserialize a DataSet](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm), is a a JSON object whose property names are the DataTable names and whose property values are arrays representing the data tables.  None of your property values are arrays, so that also fails.

Comment: Ideally, how do you want to deserialize that JSON?  Is it entirely free-form, or do you know the schema in advance?

Answer (score 0):

i gave you exaple with 3 options. deserialise to JObject so you can see structure cleaner and to class, you can play with third option and use a dictionary. you cannot deserialize to dataset due to json in not a flat object , it contains a dictionary/list in one of properties.

```
Sub Main
    Dim TheJsonInstruction As String = "{
        ""id"": ""qh06fx6"",
        ""data"": {
        ""name"": ""john"",
        ""age"": ""30""
        }
      }"
    
    Dim dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(TheJsonInstruction)
    Dim dataset2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TheJsonInstructionClass)(TheJsonInstruction)
    Dim dataset3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TheJsonInstructionClass2)(TheJsonInstruction)

    dataset.Dump
    dataset2.Dump
    dataset3.Dump
        
End Sub

Public Class TheJsonInstructionClass
    Public id As String
    Public data As DClass
    Public Sub New()
        data = New DClass
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DClass
    Public name As String
    Public age As String

    Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TheJsonInstructionClass2
    Public id As String
    Public data As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

results:

[image]